# What is wrong with the following macro usage?

Tags: c, syntax, macros, compiler-errors

`isPowerof(2)` in `main()` causes **expected ); error** ...what is wrong with this?

```
#include<stdio.h>

#define isPowerof2(n)  (!(n & (n-1))

int main(){
    int n,p;
    clrscr();
    printf("\nEnter the number to be Checked:");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    isPowerof2(n);
    printf("%d",p);

getch();
}
```

Comment: Incidentally, the expression in `isPowerof2` will indicate that zero is a power of two, which is incorrect.

Answer (score 3):

You're missing one more bracket:

```
#define isPowerof2(n)  (!(n & (n-1)))
                                    ^
```

Side note: If you don't have to use macro, use function instead.

Answer (score 1):

You open 3 parenthesis, but close only 2.

```
#define isPowerof2(n)  (!(n & (n-1)))
```

**but there is another bug.** You should add parenthesis around your macro parameter(s) or else you could have surprises.

```
#define isPowerof2(n)  (!((n) & ((n)-1)))
```

EDIT: Example of error

Invoke

```
isPowerOf2(34 >> 1)  which is not a power of 2
```

will fail, because in your case without parenthesis, it will be expanded as

```
(!(34 >> 1 & (34 >> 1-1)))
(!(17 & (34 >> 0))       // shift is lower priority than subtraction
(!(17 & 34))
(!0)
1
```

which is obviously false.

The real value with the fixed macro is

```
(!((34 >> 1) & ((34 >> 1)-1)))
(!(17 & (17-1))       // shift is lower priority than subtraction
(!(17 & 16))
(!16)
0
```